# displaying curl results using php

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search. I have one URL. Directly when executing that URL, I am getting results. But when I am trying to run this using curl, I am not getting any data. Below is my link

```
http://localhost:9200/bank/_search?q=address:mill
```

and the sample response from above link I am getting is

```
    {"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":     {"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":4.8004513,"hits":[{"_index":"bank","_type":"account","_id":"136","_score":4.8004513,"_source":{"account_number":136,"balance":45801,"firstname":"Winnie","lastname":"Holland","age":38,"gender":"M","address":"198 Mill Lane","employer":"Neteria","email":"winnieholland@neteria.com","city":"Urie","state":"IL"}
}]}}
```

below is the curl program for above url.

```
$url = "localhost:9200/bank/account/_search?q=mill";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: missing the `http://`  part on your curl script

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but why don't you use one of the php drivers for connecting to elastic?

Comment: tell me the drivers, because i don't the drives.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **HTTPGET** option of **CURLOPT** and then You need to append your parameters with the url.

Try below code :

```
 <?php
try {
$url = "http://localhost:9200/bank/_search";
$search_val     = 'mill';

$str = "q=address:".$search_val;
$url_final = $url.'?'.$str;

  $ch = curl_init();
 if (FALSE === $ch)
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_final);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$return = curl_exec ($ch);
if (FALSE === $return)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
} catch(Exception $e) {

    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);

}
curl_close ($ch);
echo $return;
?>
```

Comment: boolean false, i am getting this one

Comment: puted code in try catch block so you will get exact error of curl , updated the answer check and see what error it gives